# Obtener valor de un diccionario tras un QuerySet para utilizarlo en url tag django3

Tags: html, python, django, url

Estoy comenzando en django3, y al realizar el QuerySet en BBDD de un modelo para utilizarlo en un template mediante el tag url, obtengo un diccionario, pero no logro obtener el valor de dicho diccionario a fin de poder obtener la url deseada.

Estos son mis principales archivos

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.apps import apps

# Create your models here.

class Section(models.Model):
    section = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Sección")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="sección"
        verbose_name_plural="secciones"
        ordering=['-created']



    def __str__(self):
        return self.section

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name="Titular")
    subtitle = models.TextField(verbose_name="Subtitular")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Noticia")
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=now, verbose_name="Fecha de publicación")
    link = models.URLField(verbose_name = "Dirección web", null=False, blank=False)
    secciones = models.ManyToManyField(Section, verbose_name="Sección")
    journals = models.ManyToManyField(Journal, verbose_name="Diario")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, verbose_name="Etiquetas")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="noticia"
        verbose_name_plural="noticias"
        ordering=['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Este es el **url.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('section/<str:section_section>/', views.section, name="section"),
]
```

Y este es el **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post, Section

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, "core/home.html",{'posts':posts})

def section(request, section_section):
    section = get_object_or_404(Section, section=section_section)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(secciones=section)
    return render(request, "core/section.html", {'section':section,
                                                 'posts':posts})
```

y finalmente el html.

```
<div class="card-text"><a href="{% url 'section' post.secciones.all %}">{% for section in post.secciones.all %}{{section}}{% endfor %}</a>
```

Pero obtengo en el enlace este resultado (pongo un pantallazo, que no me deja poner los caracteres):

[image: url resultado]

cuando en realidad tendría que obtener:

127.0.0.1:8000/section/España/

Espero haber dejado clara la cuestión.

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: Estás poniendo todo un `QuerySet` en la URL. Lo que tienes que hacer es pasarle el `section.section`: `<a href="{% url 'section' section.section %}">`. ¿Es eso lo que necesitas?

Comment: Hola Ceśar! Ya lo hize y me sale esto en el navegador: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'section' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['section/(?P<section_section>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: Alguna sugerencia, @César ? Es que no logro conseguir que se quite el error. Gracias!

Comment: <div class="card-text"><a href="{% url 'section' post.secciones.section %}">{% for section in post.secciones.all %}{{section}}{% endfor %}</a> de esa forma se supone que solo filtrarias las secciones que si tienen un post, si deseas filtral todas las secciones deberias de adaptar el codigo para que funcione con el dataset de secciones y no post

Comment: Hola @edsantoshn ! Gracias por tu respuesta. Poniendo lo que me dices en tu respuesta sale el siguiente error de nuevo: Reverse for 'section' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['section/(?P<section_section>[^/]+)/$']